# Get geofence of city in google map

Tags: google-maps

Is there a function in google map that can get the geofence or the polygon area of city? For example i like to get the geofence Manila Philippines. I want to save the polygon Latitude and longitude of the city to MySql geometry column.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment there is no such function. If you search for Manila, Philippines using geocoding you will get the location with the viewport and bounding box. However you won't get a polygon around the area.

One workaround would be to create your own polygons and save them to your database and then check if the lat/long is within those polygons.

Comment: How sad, I need if to save in my database and check if the lat long is inside the city polygon. I try Reverse Geocoding https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-reverse

but if i query 1000 record and check one by one it take me too long.